# Creating a PHP API (Convert data from mySQL to JSON);

Tags: php, mysql, json

So my 1st target is to convert expecting data from mySQL as JSON before use XML.
Things i trying to solve- Connect two tables from database for specific user and display it on screen.

Everything is in one PHP file:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
 session_start();
  ob_start();
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_quiz ON users.user_uid = user_quiz.user_uid
WHERE users.user_uid = '".$_SESSION['u_uid'] ."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $outp = array();
        $outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// for check if record exist
          echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["user_first"]. " " . $row["user_last"] . " id:" . $row["user_uid"] . " Selected qustion " . $row["q_topic"] . " ". $row["q_id"] .  "<br>";

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


$myJSON = json_encode($outp);

echo $myJSON;
?>
```

So now where is a issue.. When i do SQL like that:
 SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
```

PHP is convert data as JSON data... but when i trying to do that for specific user i have empty []... That's why i use echo to see if i have output or i have error but... i have displays value...  Had no idea what's going on... need advice.

Comment: You create a while loop to consumer your result set and then inside the loop you do a `$result->fetch_all()` ???? Pick one method or the other

Comment: heh. Thats work :D  it happend becouse 1st i just echo result to get expecting output and after that traying to convert to JSON. Thanks for clue :D